# Run multiple xpath query in one xq file

Tags: xml, xpath

How to run multiple query in one xp file?

for example:

```
/descendant::test/child::* //<--First query

/descendant::test/child::name//text() //<-- second query
```

if i save both in one xp file and run them, error show out. but if one query in one xp file. it's working fine. any way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by `xq` or xp` file? Your question is not clear. Please edit it. Are you talking about XQuery or XPath? If XQuery, please tag this question as XQuery. You must add more information about your environment: version, and include code sample of your source.

Answer (score 2):

Return a tuple with the results of each query you want to run.

```
(/descendant::test/child::*,
 /descendant::test/child::name//text())
```

Of course, there are other forms you could use for this as well. For instance, you could return an XML structure with your queries indexed:

```
<results>
  <result idx="1">{/descendant::test/child::*}</result>
  <result idx="2">{/descendant::test/child::name//text()}</result>
</results>
```

Comment: ...from which of the two results, precisely?

Comment: Also, note that this answer is XQuery, not XPath.